# How to return 400 http error code instead of 401 without any scripts?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to return error code 400, when user enter bad credintials for suppress browser's basic auth dialog
But i cannot change response code on server side.
I guess it is possible with some .htaccess rules, but google don't have a answer to my question, i just found solutions for 403 -> 404, but it don't work for me.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom error responses but you cannot change the actual error code returned. That would be a very practice.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Btw, if you enter bad credentials, you will be taken to the 401 page. You'll only get the auth dialog again if you try to reload the page (or, try to load protected items from the 401 page itself, which of course creates an infinite loop and never allows you to escape the auth dialog).